# Querying a shapefile and returning values?

Tags: shapefile, web-mapping, rest

I have a lot of experience making maps in ArcMap. I don't have much experience programming or working with APIs.

Here's the (simple) problem: I create a shapefile of a region and then load the shapefile into one of many possible web mapping services (Leaflet, CartoDB, Mango Maps). How do I go about querying the shapefile to see whether a location (coded in lat/long) fell in the region's boundary? Or, say, within 'x' miles of the region. Need to eventually batch process the query. Is this just a matter of getting the syntax right with whatever REST API the web mapping service provides?

Comment: I think that this is too broad because it is effectively asking the same question about multiple web mapping products.